# Dynammically allocating array of multiple structs

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have a bunch of structures declared like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int docid;
    int freq;
} pairs_t;

typedef struct {
    char *word;
    int numlines;
    pairs_t *pairs;
    int index;
    int npairs;
} data_t;

typedef struct {
    data_t *data;
    int numwords;
} index_t;
```

Where I want to create an array of structures within `index_t`, where `index_t` will hold information about each element from `data_t`.

I am trying to

- malloc space for the array `data_t *data` within `index_t` to hold an array of structures.
- realloc more space when required for the array of structures.
- malloc enough space for each element within the array of structures

I have just been playing around with this, and this is what I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int initialsize = 1;
    int count = 0;

    index_t *index;
    index->data = (data_t*)malloc(initialsize * sizeof(data_t));

    index->data = realloc(index->data, 2 * initialsize);

    index->data[count] = malloc(sizeof(data_t));

    count++;

    return 0;
}
```

I am just wondering why my mallocing of `index->data[count]` is causing an error. This is no means a proper program, I was just wondering why this isn't working. I am just trying to see If I can get all three of these steps to work before I attempt a bigger program.

The error is:

`error: incompatible types when assigning to type "data_t" from type "void *"`

Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why my mallocing of `index->data[count]` is causing an error

It's wrong because `index->data[count]` is of the type `data_t` but not `data_t*` and so it cannot hold the address returned by `malloc()`

By the way you need not cast the value of `malloc()` as it returns `void*` which is implicitly converted to the type of variable it's getting assigned to

Apart from that, as others have pointed out you didn't initialise the `index`

---

here's a way of dealing with your problem:

```
int initialsize = 1;
int count = 0;

index_t *index;

//allocating memory for index
index = malloc(sizeof(index_t));

//allocating memory for `data`
index->data = malloc(initialsize * sizeof(data_t));

int required_size = 7; //I chose 7 randomly

//reallocating memory for `data`
index->data = realloc(index->data, required_size * sizeof(data_t));

count++;
```

---

Further, if you want to allocate memory for `pairs_t *pairs;` member of one of the elements of data this is how you can do it:

```
int required_size = 2;

index->data = malloc(required_size * sizeof(data_t));

//for first element of array
index->data[0].pairs = malloc(required_size * sizeof(pairs_t)); 
//you can even realloc
index->data[0].pairs = realloc(index->data[0].pairs, 3 * sizeof(pairs_t));
```

And by the way, don't forget to free the malloced data at the end of the program

---

Here's a sample program to sum it all up:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int docid;
    int freq;
} pairs_t;

typedef struct {
    char *word;
    int numlines;
    pairs_t *pairs;
    int index;
    int npairs;
} data_t;

typedef struct {
    data_t *data;
    int numwords;
} index_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int initialsize = 1;
    int count = 0;

    index_t *index;
    index = malloc(sizeof(index_t));

    int required_size = 1;

    index->data = malloc(required_size * sizeof(data_t));

    //for first element of array
    index->data[0].pairs = malloc(required_size * sizeof(pairs_t)); 
    //you can even realloc
    index->data[0].pairs = realloc(index->data[0].pairs, 1 * sizeof(pairs_t));

    //now you can access the members of pairs this way

    index->data[0].pairs[0].docid = 777;
    index->data[0].pairs[0].freq  = 777;

    printf("docid : %d\nfreq  : %d", index->data[0].pairs[0].docid, index->data[0].pairs[0].freq);

    free(index->data[0].pairs);
    free(index->data);
    free(index);

    count++;

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
docid : 777
freq  : 777
```

Working sample: https://ideone.com/Bg6aWa

Answer (score 1):

Yeah quite a lot wrong here.

```
index_t *index;
index->data = (data_t*)malloc(initialsize * sizeof(data_t));
```

`index` is unallocated so you need to do that first

then realloc on top of your initial allocation

If data is an array then you need to allocate an array of them (which you've got) then loop through initialising values

Answer (score 1):

```
index_t *index;
```

This defines an *uninitialised* pointer to an `index_t`.
It is pointing somewhere,
but at this point you just have no idea where.

Sadly, you then write to where this pointer is pointing!

```
index->data = ...
```

Thus overwriting some poor piece of memory.
If you are lucky this will cause your program to crash.

Do it like this:

```
index_t index;
```

`index` exists, but all its fields are uninitialised.
This time it's `index.data` that is pointing somewhere random,
but we don't care because we *never* look at where it's pointing.

```
index.data = (data_t*)malloc(1 * sizeof(data_t));
index.data[0] = malloc(sizeof(data_t));
index.data = (data_t*)realloc(index.data, 2 * sizeof(data_t));
index.data[1] = malloc(sizeof(data_t));
```